# Combining Two Arrays from Separate Classes

Tags: android, arrays, object, getter-setter

I have two arrays of objects and I am trying to combine the two in one class.

```
final Object[] newarray = ArrayUtils.addAll(part1, part2);
```

part1 is in a different class than part2. I know the code above is wrong, please don't correct me on that. That is just how I am going to add the two. I have tried setting up setter and getter methods with no luck. Am I going about this the wrong way?

EDIT:

```
Class 1 {

Object[] part1 = new Object[]{

            new Object(),
            new Object(),
            new Object(),
            new Object(),
            new Object(),
}

Class 2 {
Object[] part2 = new Object[]{


            new Object(),
            new Object(),
            new Object(),
            new Object(),
            new Object(),
}



  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final Object[] newarray = ArrayUtils.addAll(part1, part2);
ArrayAdapter<Object> myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Object>(this, R.layout.row, newarray);

        busroutelist.setAdapter(myAdapter);
}
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use a loop?

Comment: @AlexTerreaux Yeah I could do that. My biggest problem is referencing the other array in the other class

Comment: I would need to see the code of both classes where the arrays are declared to help you more.

Comment: @AlexTerreaux I updated the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you don't have instances of those classes, you would need to do the following:

```
final Object[] newarray = ArrayUtils.addAll(new Class1().part1, new Class2().part2);
```

That way you are creating an instance of each class, and once the instances exist, you can access the properties they hold. I recommend you review some object oriented programming theory to better understand the what a classes, instances and objects are and how they work.

Comment: Dude seriously thanks so much. I will check that out. Really appreciate the help